# Scrolling issue in Laravel Dusk

Tags: jquery, laravel, offset, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to do test cases for my application on Laravel 6.0 with Dusk. I'm facing some difficulties in finding the element, while browsing through few topics I achieved solutions through scrolling the browser. As per the documentation I created a macro in my `ServiceProvider`:

```
Browser::macro('scrollToElement', function ($element = null) {
    $this->script("$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('$element').offset().top }, 0);");

    return $this;
});
```

I can easily use this and scroll my elements, but I have sticky head bar which comes while scrolling the top element. I need to make visible one element which is on top of the table:

[image]

Button which I want to achieve is circled with red color. When I do scroll I get screenshot from Dusk where I can see my button has been hidden by the header.

[image]

My code looks like:

```
$browser->maximize();
$browser->scrollToElement('#company-add-button')
        ->pause(500)
```

In fact I tried modifying the `x,y` values of offset/window, but no luck:

```
Browser::macro('scrollToElement', function ($element = null) {
    $this->script("$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: parseInt($('$element').offset().top, 10) + 100 }, 0);");

    return $this;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be *subtracting* the offset? You want to scroll *less far* down the page than the element actually is. Or maybe scroll to the top, as it looks like it's in the viewport there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Silly mistake, Thanks, it helped.